# How to export filtered data from django-filters in csv fromat

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, export-to-csv, django-filter

I have a model like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and implemented django-filters like this:

In `filter.py`:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from api.models import Location

class LocationFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    id = filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    address = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'address',]
```

In `views.py`:

```
from api.filter import LocationFilter

class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = LocationFilter
```

URL-`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/location/?id=&name=Cafe&address=` return  all data consisting location named cafe.

How can i export it to a `CSV` file?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it by writing a export function for accessing the filtered queryset [**.qs** attribute [readthedocs.io]](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs)

In `views.py`:

```
def export_filter_location(request):
    location = Location.objects.all()
    filter = LocationFilter(request.GET, queryset=location).qs
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    file_name = "fltred_loaction_data" + str(datetime.today()) + ".csv"

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['id','Name', 'Name_short_code', 'Address'])
    for i in filter.values_list('id','name', 'name_short_code', 'address'):
        writer.writerow(i)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = "' + file_name + '"'
    return response
```